# check every line in the listview in vb.net?

Tags: regex, vb.net, listview

I Have a List View in my form and the listview have alot of items in there I want to check every line on the list view if the line have A Special string like 
127.0.0.1 the line will be deleted I tried to do  this there is my code

```
Dim was As Integer
    For Each item In ListView1.Items
        was = ListView1.Items.Count - 1
        ListView1.SelectedIndices.Add(was)
        ListView1.Focus()
        If ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(2).Text().Contains("127.0.0.1") Then
            Dim a As ListViewItem
            a = ListView1.SelectedItems(0)
            a.Remove()
        End If
    Next
```

this is example of one line in the listview

```
first examble :TCP#127.0.0.1:5939#127.0.0.1:54741#ESTABLISHED#3620
second example :TCP#192.168.1.5:3488#52.230.84.0:443#ESTABLISHED#3732
```

I spilt the string to add it to listview 
I want to delete the first example you see but the second example I want to keep it
Take Care the lines is untidiness
Thanks in advance

Comment: How is the string split when you add it to the list view? `.SubItems(2)` will look at the third column in a list view

Comment: `.SelectedItems` will only return the items that are currently selected, not all the items in the list. Perhaps you should try the `.Items` collection

Comment: Why are you not using item?  `If item.SubItems(2).Text.Contains("127.0.0.1") then  item.remove End If` you might however need to do a `For Each item as listviewitem in Listview1.Items` to ensure that it's seen as a listviewitem. **this should only be 5 lines of code including the for each and next lines**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By specifying that item is of type ListViewItem in the for...each you can expose the properties from item.

```
    For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
        If item.SubItems(2).Text.Contains("127.0.0.1") Then
            item.Remove()
        End If
    Next
```

Once you find an `item` that meets the `If` criteria, just remove().

@Mary
Here is the test code that is based off of my answer. Add a listview with 3 columns to the form and a button

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim lv As New ListViewItem
    lv.Text = "able"
    lv.SubItems.Add("baker")
    lv.SubItems.Add(":TCP#127.0.0.1# ESTABLISHED3620")
    ListView1.Items.Add(lv)

    lv = New ListViewItem
    lv.Text = "able"
    lv.SubItems.Add("baker")
    lv.SubItems.Add(":TCP#127.0.0.1# ESTABLISHED3620")
    ListView1.Items.Add(lv)

    lv = New ListViewItem
    lv.Text = "able"
    lv.SubItems.Add("baker")
    lv.SubItems.Add(":TCP#127.0.4.1:5939#127.0.4.1:54741#ESTABLISHED#3620")
    ListView1.Items.Add(lv)

    lv = New ListViewItem
    lv.Text = "able"
    lv.SubItems.Add("baker")
    lv.SubItems.Add(":TCP#127.0.0.1# ESTABLISHED3620")
    ListView1.Items.Add(lv)
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each itm As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
        If itm.SubItems(2).Text.Contains("127.0.0.1") Then
            itm.Remove()
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The reason this works has something to do with how the IEnumerable interface was implemented. I'm trying to find the article, but it has to do with affecting a local copy and not the actual collection.

I will say however after reading up on this, that it is probably best to stick to the reverse for...loop since most will fail when changing the size of the collection.

Comment: You cannot mess with the Items while you are iterating them in a For Each. Use a For ...Next

Comment: @Mary, I added an example. I've found this works with Listview and dataGridView and there is a way to actually do it with a listbox containing strings or objects.

Comment: man you are alegend thank you so much it's work so good ou make me happy ^-^

Comment: @CharlesMay You are correct. I fooled around with this a bit and I get the error I expected with a simple List(Of T) System.InvalidOperationException: 'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.' but the ListViewItemsCollection must be a different type of animal. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

If you are removing items in a collection you cannot use a For Each to iterate. Get the count before the loop because count will change as the loop runs. Subtract one because indexes are zero based. Iterate backwards because if you do it forwards the indexes change when an item is removed and items will be skipped and eventually an index will be out of range.

```
Private Sub IterateListView()
        Dim count As Integer = ListView1.Items.Count - 1
        For index = count To 0 Step -1
            If ListView1.Items(index).SubItems(2).Text.Contains("127.0.0.1") Then
                ListView1.Items(index).Remove()
            End If
        Next
 End Sub
```